# How would I retrieve an array of data outside an extension class in the same script

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have this custom scrollview for my app, and I have an array of data that's inside my main delegate class. I also have a separate extension (in the same file) to handle the data, but I can't seem to be able to access the data with two errors `Use of unresolved identifier data`:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let data = [
        CustomData(title: "Test", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash_icon"), url: "clipifyapp.com"),
        CustomData(title: "Test2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "done-button"), url: "clipifyapp.com"),
        CustomData(title: "Test2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "notificationIcon"), url: "clipifyapp.com")
    ]

}

extension UIViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count // ERROR ONE
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.data = self.data[indexPath.row] // ERROR TWO
        return cell
    }

}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `data` is defined in a sub-class of `UIViewController` so you can't access it from the superclass or an extension to the superclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is available only in `HomeViewController`, not in base class `UIViewController`

Replace

```
extension UIViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

with

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are extending `UIViewController`, but didn't you mean to extend `HomeViewController` instead?

If you extend `UIViewController`, you are not extending the subclass which actually contains `data`. Besides, you would be extending every single UIViewController in your whole app, which is probably not something you want to do with a UICollectionViewDataSource.